# How to get current glDebugMessageCallback?

Tags: opengl

I'm creating a shared OpenGL context in my library. And I want to set the debugging parameters as they are in the context of the application that is using the library.

Is it possible to query the MessageCallback and DebugMessageControl parameters directly from the context, so there is no need to pass them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`glGetPointerv()`](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glGetPointerv.xhtml) with `GL_DEBUG_CALLBACK_FUNCTION` or `GL_DEBUG_CALLBACK_USER_PARAM`.

`glDebugMessageControl()` state does not appear to be query-able as of GL 4.5.